# C#: What's the String.Format form of this?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

How can this easy to write (and read) string formatting routine be convert into the "proper" `String.Format` equivalent code?

```
Int32 power;
Single voltage;
Int32 kVA;
Double powerFactor;

powerFactor = power / kVA;

label1.Text = 
      DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + 
      power.ToString() + "W,  " + 
      voltage.ToString() + "V "+
      "(pf "+(powerFactor*100.0).ToString()+"%)";

//label1.Text = String.Format("{g}: {0:g}W, {0:g}V (p.f. {0:0%}%)", 
//      DateTime.Now, power, voltage, powerFactor);
```

I've spent about 10 minutes trying to use `String.Format`; the person who documented it should be terminated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string.Format("{0}: {1}W,  {2}V (pf {3}%",DateTime.Now,power,voltage,powerFactor*100)
```

So, here is the thing that I think is confusing you. Every `{0}` is the index of the objects you are passing in. `{0}` is the first object, `{1}` the second, and so forth.  You can also specify formats, widths, and other things too numerous to list here. I use [SteveX string ref](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/) for most of my needs.

```
label1.Text = String.Format("{0:g}: {1:g}W, {2:g}V (p.f. {3:0.0%})", 
      DateTime.Now, power, voltage, powerFactor);
```

Comment: Which ironically is the site i have open on another tab; nobody has multiple value examples. It took quite a bit of hunting to find the syntax for multiple parameters (one site gave it as `String.Format("...", new Object[] {value1, value2, value3})`

Comment: +amillion - I wish I could up vote you a couple of times for the SteveX String Formatting FAQ. There is definitely stuff in there that I hadn't seen before.

Comment: lol I use it enough that I have it bookmarked in all my browswers